# How to know from where the Extension in MS Teams is initiated?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have running MS Teams App which includes Bot Framework and Extension. On clicking the Extension the app opens up the Task Module which further runs Angular Application.

My question here is how I can get to know from what team/chat the extension is opened?

[image]

Comment: You can get the bot context https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/get-teams-context?tabs=dotnet#get-teams-details. However there is no context for ME.

Comment: Can you provide me an example?

Comment: TeamsInfo.GetTeamDetailsAsync is being used here - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/8f266c33608d6d7b4cf89c81779ccf49e7664c1e/samples/msteams-application-qbot/Source/Microsoft.Teams.Apps.QBot.Web/Bot/QBotTeamInfo.cs#L44